# inserting values into multiple tables PHP

Tags: php, web-services, mysqli

I am stuck at writing this kind of service where information is being added into multiple tables. my connection is established column names are perfect but don't know why my first insert query doesn't work. FYI i am testing this service by REST api Client. Please help me out..

```
<?php
include_once 'connection.php';
$json = "";
$userId;
$shareId;
if ($_SERVER ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    if (isset ( $_POST ["alarmId"] ) && isset ( $_POST ["phone"] ) && isset ( $_POST ["title"] ) && isset ( $_POST ["time"] ) && isset ( $_POST ["ringtone"] ) && isset ( $_POST ["snoozeDuration"] ) && isset ( $_POST ["gentleWakeup"] ) && isset ( $_POST ["mon"] ) && isset ( $_POST ["tues"] ) && isset ( $_POST ["wed"] ) && isset ( $_POST ["thu"] ) && isset ( $_POST ["fri"] ) && isset ( $_POST ["sat"] ) && isset ( $_POST ["sun"] ) && isset ( $_POST ["isOn"] ) && isset ( $_POST ["isShared"] ) && isset ( $_POST ["isRepeating"] ) && 
     //share content
    isset ( $_POST ["shallInform"] ) && isset ( $_POST ["textMsg"] ) && isset ( $_POST ["contacts"] )) {

        // alarm content..
        $alarmId = $_POST ["alarmId"];
        $phone = $_POST ["phone"];
        $title = $_POST ["title"];
        $time = $_POST ["time"];
        $date = $_POST ["date"];
        $ringtone = $_POST ["ringtone"];
        $snoozeDur = $_POST ["snoozeDuration"];
        $gentleWake = $_POST ["gentleWakeup"];
        $mon = $_POST ["mon"];
        $tues = $_POST ["tues"];
        $wed = $_POST ["wed"];
        $thu = $_POST ["thu"];
        $fri = $_POST ["fri"];
        $sat = $_POST ["sat"];
        $sun = $_POST ["sun"];
        $isOn = $_POST ["isOn"];
        $isShared = $_POST ["isShared"];
        $isRepeating = $_POST ["isRepeating"];

        // share content...
        $shallInform = $_POST ["shallInform"];
        $textMsg = $_POST ["textMsg"];
        ##$contact_list = $_POST ["contacts"];

        //inserting into alarm table..

        $s1 = "INSERT INTO alarm (alarmId,phone,title,time,date,ringtone,snoozeDuration,gentleWakeup,isMon,isTues,isWed,isThu,isFri,isSat,isSun,isOn,isShared,isRepeating) VALUES ('$alarmId','$phone','$title','$time', '$date' ,'$ringtone','$snoozeDur','$gentleWake','$mon','$tues','$wed','$thu','$fri','$sat','$sun','$isOn','$isShared','$isRepeating')";

        $qur = mysqli_query ( $con, $s1 );

        if ($qur) {
            echo "if it is inside.....";
            $json = array (
                    "status_code" => 200,
                    "message" => "alarm is successfully added" 
            );
            //getting user id..

            $getUserId = "SELECT userId from users WHERE phone = '" . $phone . "' LIMIT 1 ";
            $userQuery = mysqli_query ( $con, $getUserId );
            if($userQuery){
                while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $userQuery ) ) {
                    $userId = $row ['userId'];
                }   
            }
            else{
                $json = array (
                    "status_code" => 0,
                    "message" => "Invalid phone number, Alarm isn't added" 
            );
            }


            //inserting into share table..

            $insShare = "INSERT INTO share (alarmId,userId,shallInform,textMsg) VALUES ('$alarmId','$userId','$shallInform','$textMsg')";
            $shareResult = mysqli_query ( $con, $insShare );

            if($shareResult){
                $shareId = mysqli_insert_id ( $con );
            }// end of share insert Query
            else{
                $json = array (
                        "status_code" => 0,
                        "message" => "content to be shared cannot added"
                );
            }

            // sharing alarm with friends...
            for($i=0;$i<count($contact_list);$i++){
                $shareAlarm = "INSERT INTO shared_with (shareId,friendId)VALUES ('$shareId,'$contact_list[i])";
                $shareResult = mysqli_query($shareAlarm);

                if($shareResult){

                }
                else{
                    $json = array (
                            "status_code" => 0,
                            "message" => "alarm isn't shared"
                    );

                }


            }



        } else {
            $json = array (
                    "status_code" => 0,
                    "message" => "error adding alarm" 
            );
        }
    }
} else {
    $json = array (
            "status_code" => 400,
            "message" => "Request method not accepted" 
    );
}

    enter code here

mysqli_close ( $con );
//header ( 'Content-type: application/json' );
if ($json != "") {

    echo json_encode ( $json );
} else {
    $json = array (
            "status_code" => 0,
            "message" => "please set all required values before transmitting to server" 
    );
    echo json_encode ( $json );
}
?>
```

My connection.php file is

```
<?php

            define("SERVER", '127.0.0.1');
            define("USER", 'root');
            define("PASSWORD", "");
            define("DB", 'alarm_clock');


            $con = new mysqli(SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DB);

            if ($con->connect_errno){
                die("Database Connection Failed");
                exit();

            }
```

Comment: unless all your fields in `share` are varchar/char, then the insert wont work.. also post your table definition and the exact sql that is being generated ( echo `$shareAlarm` )

Comment: my first insert query, INSERT INTO alarm gets nothing and if ($qur) {} always return false. I am going to add table definition in post. thanks

Comment: Don't enclose your variables in single qoutation

Comment: isn't it php syntax to enclose variables in single quotation?

Answer (score 0):

It should work

```
$s1 = "INSERT INTO alarm (`alarmId`,`phone`,`title`,`time`,`date`,`ringtone`,`snoozeDuration`,`gentleWakeup`,`isMon`,`isTues`,`isWed`,`isThu`,`isFri`,`isSat`,`isSun`,`isOn`,`isShared`,`isRepeating`) VALUES ('$alarmId','$phone','$title','$time', '$date' ,'$ringtone','$snoozeDur','$gentleWake','$mon','$tues','$wed','$thu','$fri','$sat','$sun','$isOn','$isShared','$isRepeating')";
```

Please noted that time, date etc are mysql reserved keywords, you should use `time` instead of time and so on

Comment: thanks. i didn't get you. what should i use instead of time. ?

Comment: sorry stackoverflow removed backtick. Edited